# Cannot access Interface defined in the Code Sharing Project from within UWP project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, uwp

I am just a newbie in Xamarin, so I tried creating the simple *Phoneword* application available at [Xamarin on-line guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/).

The solution created in Visual Studio comprises 4 distinct Projects:

1. A portable class library (PCL) project that holds all of the shared code
2. A project that holds Android specific code
3. A project that holds iOS specific code
4. A project that holds Universal Windows Platform (UWP) specific code

This is how the solution structure looks like:

[image]

Now inside the first project an interface has been declared:

```c#
namespace Phoneword
{
    public interface IDialer
    {
        bool Dial(string number);
    }
}
```

I now try to use this interface from within the UWP project:

```c#
using Phoneword.UWP;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PhoneDialer))]
namespace Phoneword.UWP
{
    public class PhoneDialer : IDialer
    {
      ...
```

**Building** the solution ends successfully. But when I try to **Deploy**
the UWP project I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'IDialer' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone give me hint on what could be the source of this error?

**Update**

There was one more error I was getting when I tried to deploy:

> Error DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80070005] error
>   0x80070005: Opening file from location: AppxManifest.xml failed with
>   error: Access is denied.

I closed the solution, exited Visual Studio started and loaded again and the first error disappeared. So, it seems, there is nothing wrong in consuming an interface, declared in the Code Sharing Project, from within the UWP Project.

The actual error I was getting was due to access rights restrictions of the folder were the project was being deployed.

Comment: Is the DLL with the interface in actually being deployed?

Comment: @DavidG I really don't know, I just followed every single step of the tutorial. According to the guide the project should successfully deploy, but for my test environment it somehow doesn't.

Comment: What are you deploying to?

Comment: I am deploying to `'Local machine'`. I should see a window with a textbox popping up.

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing the `Phoneword` in your `PhoneDialer.cs` file. Add this to the top:

```
using Phoneword; // <== Add this
using Phoneword.UWP;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Xamarin.Forms;
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the error appears when trying to deploy the project. The solution builds ok.

Comment: Does it say which file the exception occurs?

Comment: Yes, it is `PhoneDialer.cs` of `PhoneWord.UWP` project. I also get the same error for `PhoneDialer.cs` of `PhoneWord.iOS` but *not* for `PhoneDialer.cs` of `PhoneWord.Android`.

Comment: It doesn't give a red squiggly under the `IDialer` in the `PhoneDialer.cs` file?

Comment: Yes, it does give a red squiggly under the `IDialer` name. The tooltip when I hover over the name is the same as the error message cited in the OP.

Comment: What does `Ctrl+.` suggest?

Comment: To generate the interface

Comment: Does it work if you right click the PCL project and choose *Build*, and then try to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The way to fix it is just to restart Visual Studio or reload the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Add this to your code at the top

> > using static Phoneword.MainPage;

and it should work fine
The reason it was not working is because you didn't have a reference to it. For some reason the Assets that you import for that course do not have this reference in it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
You need to right click on the Phoneword project in the Solution Explorer and click build to build it on it's own.

Then add the using statement for the Phoneword project to your PhoneDialer file.

The reference to IDialer then becomes available.